# Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource '****.io' not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to set a new DNS record on my App Service. After the deployment step in my release pipeline: (I've formatted it for easy reading)

```
New-AzDnsRecordSet 
    -Name "e*****e.staging" 
    -ZoneName e***d.io 
    -ResourceGroupName c***2 
    -RecordType A 
    -Ttl 600 
    -DnsRecords (New-AzDnsRecordConfig -IPv4Address **.**.***.57)
```

When the script runs I get a:

> Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'e***.io' not found.

Any suggestions what I forgot to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means your dns zone doesnt exist, is called differently, is in another resource group\subscription or you dont have rights to modify it. Something along those lines.

Recheck your inputs

Comment: Thanks, I just checked our DNS zones in Azure Portal and indeed there´s no DNS zone linked to the resource.

Comment: I was only posting what the issue was... There was no DNS Zone linked to the Resource Group. So I added that and it resolved the issue.

Comment: @4c74356b41 would it be possible to connect an app service with a container registry which is in a separate resource group?

Comment: it should be, but i haven't tried that